# ListView getting clicked view and corrosponding row

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I want to get clicked row from listview child's onClick event. I am able to get clicked item but not clicked row in that event. Please, help me to get the solution.

Thanks in advance!.
My code is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Holder holder = new Holder();

        pos = position;

        if(convertView == null)
        {

            System.out.println(position);


            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,(ViewGroup)parent.findViewById(R.layout.list_layout));

            holder.form_name  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
            holder.form_details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_text);

            holder.form_details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    System.out.println(pos);
                                   //Here i am able to get clicked view but pos has always 
                    // last value
                    System.out.println("button view clicked for "+cipt_list.get(pos).cipt);

                }});


            System.out.println(holder.form_name);

            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }
        else{

            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ciptDetails cipt = cipt_list.get(position);

        holder.form_name.setText(cipt.cipt);

        return convertView;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before setting on click listener:

```
holder.form_details.setId(position);
```

and inside the onClick Method:

`v.getId()` will give you the position.

Answer (score 1):

Two way we can have position in click event:
1) Using OnItemClickListener

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

        }
    };
```

2) In getView() method you get the position. Just change it to "final int position" then you can access in view's onClickListener()

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    Holder holder = new Holder();

    pos = position;

    if(convertView == null)
    {

        System.out.println(position);


        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,(ViewGroup)parent.findViewById(R.layout.list_layout));

        holder.form_name  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
        holder.form_details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_text);

        holder.form_details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // you can access the position here
                System.out.println(pos);
                               //Here i am able to get clicked view but pos has always 
                // last value
                System.out.println("button view clicked for "+cipt_list.get(pos).cipt);

            }});


        System.out.println(holder.form_name);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    }
    else{

        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ciptDetails cipt = cipt_list.get(position);

    holder.form_name.setText(cipt.cipt);

    return convertView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method. The third argument is the position holding the information you clicked in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean clicked row from list adapter? If so, use listAdatper.get(position)

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be just to create a subclass for the listner with an int value for the row like so

```
private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
  int row;
  public MyClickListener(int r){
    row = r;
  }
  //rest of your code goes here
  ...
}
```

now when you create it just call this instead

```
 holder.form_details.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(pos));
```